# How to set AspectFit background image of UIButton in iOS Developement

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, touch

I am working on project in which I need increase button height to make more touch responsive but I have smaller image 17px, so I set button height equal to 17px so thats why its touch has not good response. So I want to increase button height at least 34px, I did this but image is getting pixelated.
I set image as a background image because there is title label also in button.
I found following solution but this is for normal image not background.
So if someone did this already kindly help me on this.

```
    [self.acceptButton setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[self.acceptButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"friends-off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Looking for help. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to do that from the interface builder and it just didn't stretch the image, try to do that instead of setting the image in the code.

Comment: try replace ure code with [self.acceptButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"friends-off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

UIButton is tricky when dealing with background images at a different size than the button size. Would you consider separating the image from the button? It is less straight-forward but will give you the most flexibility with positioning your image and determining it's size.

So, if it works for you, simply place a UIImage behind the transparent button that contains the text, and you'll have full control over the image's size and position.